# REST API call to Nominatum gets HTTP 200 on Linux but HTTP 400 on Windows

Tags: java, rest, http, nominatim

I had server app which is written on Java. It does http request to public geocoding API (Nominatium). On my linux machine on GET request to API im getting 200 OK. On windows im getting this:

Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: http://192
.168.239.72/search/polska/WARSZAWA/POSTĘPU/17?format=json&

Any ideas?

Comment: 400 is for Bad request. Can you share the whole request parameters that you are passing and are they encoded?

Comment: are you sure its sending the same request each time? maybe there are some environment variables or configuration settings different between the linux and windows machines? Can you debug the app?

Comment: Why is there a space between 192 and the dot for 168?